# How to get client timezone in utc format like (UTC+05:00) in php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, utc

I want to get timezone of visitors of my application in UTC format like (UTC+05:00) in php or javascript.

I have already tried this but it does not help me out it returns the result as 
Asia/Karachi:

```
$time ="<script>document.write(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone);</script>";
echo $time;
```

Result: Asia/Karachi

I want to get result in UTC format like (UTC+05:00). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a javascript solution :

```js
let date = new Date(); 
console.log('UTC' + 
(-date.getTimezoneOffset() < 0 ? '-' : '+') + 
(Math.abs(date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60) < 10 ? '0' : '') + 
(Math.abs(date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60)) + ':00'
);
```

Comment: yeah thanks for reply upto some extent its fine like if time zone minutes are 00  ((UTC+06:00)) then its works fine but after changing timezone to country like india where value of minutes are not 00 ((UTC+06:30)) then it return wrong timezone

Comment: So complete it with a module instead of ':00' ?