# Get current datetime in specific time zone with specific format

Tags: javascript, datetime, datetime-format

I'm using javascript only (not allowed to use any 3rd party js), and i want to retrieve current datetime in UTC+7 with a format like this `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSTZD` for example:

```
2019-05-14T16:36:20.000+07:00
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) you can accomplish that like so:

```js
console.log(moment().utcOffset(7).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i need it in pure javascript

Comment: in pure JS you will need to parse it yourslef

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
```

```js
let date = new Date(); 

console.log('UTC' + (-date.getTimezoneOffset() < 0 ? '-' : '+') + (Math.abs(date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60) < 10 ? '0' : '') + (Math.abs(date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60)) + ':00');
```

Comment: See this post to complete this answer with UTC :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55903592/how-to-get-client-timezone-in-utc-format-like-utc0500-in-php-or-javascript/55905225#55905225